# msbuild deployonbuild trying to publish different project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, publish

I have an MVC site that I am publishing through the command line using the arguments

```
msbuild.exe /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test MyProject.csproj
```

The `MyProject`project has a reference to another web application project `MyReferencedProject`. This is used to store shared Razor views and other shared code with another web site. (Making the project type as a Web Application was recommended by RazorGenerator so that I get intellisense when working with Razor views) This project functions like a class library, and should never be published.

The issue is that when I run the command above, I get the error that it can't find the `Test.pubxml` for `MyReferencedProject`:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4352,5): error : The value for PublishProfile is set to 'Test', expected to find the file at 'C:\Projects\MyReferencedProject\Properties\PublishProfiles\Test.pubxml' but it could not be found.

How can I run msbuild to publish `MyProject` without it also trying to publish `MyReferencedProject`?

I found I can work around the issue by adding a `Test` publish profile for this project, but that means I have to set up some place to put the code when it's published, which really shouldn't be generated at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your command line to:

`msbuild.exe /p:DeployMyProject=true /p:PublishProfile=Test MyProject.csproj`

Then add the following property group to `MyProject.csproj` before any `Import` statements:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DeployOnBuild Condition="'$(DeployMyProject)'!=''">$(DeployMyProject)</DeployOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This solution is based on: [How to publish one web project from a solution](http://sedodream.com/2013/03/06/HowToPublishOneWebProjectFromASolution.aspx).